# Ho can I light number of LEDs based on current flowing through circuit

Tags: led, current, water, tank

I am trying to create a water tank level indicator which will have 2 wires going into tank one with resistors attached at increment levels and one simple wire. Is it possible to light up number of LEDs based on current flowing through circuit.

Some of the solutions refer to lm3914 and measure the voltage and light LEDs based on that but can anybody explain how that will work with this design.

Thank you

Comment: You need to provide much more detail about the proposed tank sensor circuit.

Comment: There are hundreds, even thousands, of circuits for doing this, from simpler ones with single transistors for each water level, all the way up to complex IoT circuits. The solution you described (only 2 wires going to the tank) is feasible, but it will need a circuit to handle the signal coming from those two wires. You could learn many useful things that could help you to solve your problem for yourself if you just did a generic Google search for "simple water tank level circuit".

Comment: Note that a 'float' type sensor is immune to chemicals and minerals in the water.